# Reset a grafana panel chart every 14 days

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I am using grafana to see the evolution of images taken every 14 days.
The date of the images is stored within an postgresql table. At every beginning of the 14 days session, I would like the total number of images taken to be reset to 0. Then the number is incremented for each image, until we reach the next 14 days.
I know how to sort the images by date given a certain starting point, but how do I reset this starting point every two weeks ?

Thanks for the help :)

I considered declaring a global variable and increment it each day with if statements, but there has got to be a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You *reset* the counter with `group by`. The following gets the complete date range in a CTE then uses that in a recursive CTE to build a series [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) entries of 14 days each. Finally the main query counts the number of dates falling in each range (see Table [9.54. Range Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html)) grouping by the start date for each range. ([demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jq-M2yng))

```
with recursive 
     dr as ( select min(date_stored) low_dt
                  , max(date_stored) hi_dt
               from images
           ) --select * from dr
   , ranges (range14, hi_dt) as 
     ( select daterange(low_dt, low_dt+13, '[]'), hi_dt from dr
       union all
       select daterange(upper(range14), upper(range14)+14, '[]'), hi_dt  
         from ranges 
        where upper(range14) <= hi_dt
     )  --select * from ranges;
select lower(range14) "14 Day Session Start"
     , count(*)       "Num Rows" 
  from ranges r 
  join images i 
    on (i.date_stored <@ r.range14) 
  group by lower(range14);
```